# How to re-enable notifications for python after disabling it in windows?

Tags: python, windows, notifications

I made a simple python program to show a system notification and I decided to disable notifications for python for some time and enable it again afterwards in Windows settings > System > Notifications & Actions, however python was not in the list of apps that show notifications.

HOW DO I ENABLE IT AGAIN?

Is possible to do it with the code itself or with command prompt or by any other means?

Code:

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
notif = ToastNotifier()
notif.show_toast("ALERT", "TEST1", icon_path="C:/Windows/SystemApps/Microsoft.Windows.SecHealthUI_cw5n1h2txyewy/Assets/Device.contrast-white.ico", duration=5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

6 Steps to solve this problem:

1 - Open both Settings > System > Notifications & Actions and wherever you run your program (Example - Terminal or IDE)

---

2 - Increase the time of the notification to be shown by python to a large number like 50 seconds, by changing the duration argument in *.show_toast()

---

3 - Run your script and quickly refresh the app list found in the Settings window you
opened in step 1 by going to another tab such as Sound and coming back to the previous tab

---

4 - Now that your program is running and trying to display a notification, Python will be added to the list in until the time duration is elapsed, quickly turn on Python just like how you would for any other app.

---

5 - Close settings and terminate your script.

---

6 - Run your script again and the notification you were trying to display should now come as usual.

Comment: I have disabled notifications triggered by `notify-py`. This trick does not work. Any ideas?